# XPath for attribute containing spaces

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to select a checkbox attribute in xpath which is named "checked type".

I've tried //*[@checked type], //*[@checked-type], //*[@checked_type], and //*[@checked\stype] but none of them appear to be selecting any elements, while //*[@type] is working fine.

Is it possible to select an attribute with spaces?

Comment: Can you share an example of the element you would like to match?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Post the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>checked</kbd> and <kbd>type</kbd> are 2 attributes but not one, that's the reason why you are not able select the element using `//[@checked type], //[@checked-type], //[@checked_type], and //[@checked\stype]` locators.

You can define the checkbox status using <kbd>checked</kbd> attribute as shown in the below sample html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
 <label> Checkbox Checked - Using checked attribute value</label>
 <input checked='checked' type='checkbox'></input>
</div> 
<div>
 <label> Checked - simple approach</label>
 <input checked type='checkbox' ></input>
</div> 
<div>
 <label> No Checked attribut</label>
 <input  type='checkbox'></input>
</div>

<div>
 <label> Radio Checked - Using checked attribute value</label>
 <input checked='checked' type='radio'></input>
</div>
<div>
 <label> Radio Not Checked - No checked attribute value</label>
 <input type='radio'></input>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to set the checkbox/radio 'selected' by default then you can use either `checked` without attribute value or `checked='checked'`.

Refer to `checked` attribute in [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) page for more information.

So now, let's see how you can select the element.

[image]

**Checkbox**

```
 //input[@checked][@type='checkbox']
 //input[@checked='checked'][@type='checkbox']
```

**Radio:**

```
 //input[@checked][@type='radio']
 //input[@checked='checked'][@type='radio']
```